# Get Full Username of Logged In User

Tags: dominotogo

Is there a way to the full username of an authenticated user? I want to return: `CN=Ryan Buening/OU=ABC/O=Acme`

`dtgSession.username` returns the abbreviated username: 'Ryan Buening'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Domino To Go at this time. dtgSession.username only returns what you have set with dtgSession.setUsername() before.

To get the canonicalized name, DTG would need to make a HTTP request in order to ask Domino for the name. That would be possible, but is not implemented yet.

Update: Domino To Go 2.0 will have a new method notesSession.evaluate() which can be used to evaluate an @formula like "@UserName" and thus get the canonical user name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are programming in, and what interface you have. From the question, I assume that this is somewhat resembling `LDAP` (or `Active Directory`) interface. Being familiar with LDAP, I'll suggest you try using the `Distinguished Name` or `DN`. According to the syntax, this should look like any of the following:

```
dtgSession.DN
dtgSession.dn
dtgSession.Dn
dtgSession.DistinguishedName
dtgSession.distinguishedname
dtgSession.distinguishedName
```

Check [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahy%2Frzahyunderdn.htm) out for an explanation of DN. Don't confuse this with `RDN`, as this is the `Relative Distinguished Name` and probably not what you're looking for.

I hope this helps :)